# Gulp gulp-livingcss Options Not Working

Tags: gulp

I'm having issues loading the original stylesheet (CSS file) into my style guide. The gulp plugin is **gulp-livingcss** and everything is working fine except the options.

I'm calling style-guide via a gulp-watch and the output is an index.html file that renders as expected (except the original CSS file is not being referenced). I'm not getting any errors when I run the script either.

Here's my gulp snippet:

```
gulp.task('style-guide', function () {
  gulp.src('./app/temp/styles/styles.css')
    .pipe(livingcss({
      loadcss: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/style-guide'))
});
```

And here's the documentation from this page:

https://github.com/straker/livingcss#options

This is the gulp-livingcss page

https://github.com/straker/gulp-livingcss

**loadcss** - If the style guide should load the css files that were used to generate it. The style guide will not move the styles to the output directory but will merely link to the styles in their current directory (so relative paths from the styles still work). Defaults to true.

Thanks in advance